# How to search .tex files in some file manager of Chromebook?

Tags: latex, chromebook

I am trying to search .tex files in Chromebook. 
The format is not within the allowed formats in the OS. 
You can search .txt files in contrast, but I do no want to change the filenames between systems. 
I did not find any application in the Google's store about the feature. 
I reviewed the application "File Manager" but it does not allow browse Google Drive's files in the browser. 
The frontend can be Browser's view.

I am thinking if there are a possibility of creating a completely new file manager, which is using Google Drive Api, but focusing in user's wanted fileformats.

How can you search .tex files in Chromebook?

Comment: I think that Chrome OS is not the right operating system for you. You can try various methods of putting a new OS on the Chromebook or just get a new laptop that's more appropriate.